# Web - таинственные пробелы

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, сразу говорю, в Веб "программировании" я чайник. Возникла такая проблема, я адаптировал страницу и теперь при уменьшении  и расширении страницы, возникают некие пробелы между текстом. С чем это связано, дайте совет пожалуйста! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: стоит text-align: justify; и большие слова не помещаются в строку, а те что поменьше пытаются "заполнить строку"

Comment: MedvedevDev , спасибо!))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тег `<wbr>` введён в HTML5 и создаёт перенос слов при необходимости. В тех местах, где по правилам русского языка допустим перенос, вставляем `<wbr>`. Если слово целиком помещается в отведённую ширину, этот тег никак себя не проявит и о его наличии мы даже не узнаем. Если слово не помещается, браузер в месте нахождения тега `<wbr>` создаёт перенос.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Переносы</title>
  <style>
   .word { 
    width: 160px; 
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p class="word">Одиннадцатиклас<wbr>сница Анжелика 
  после окончания школы выбрала профессию 
  дело<wbr>произ<wbr>водитель<wbr>ницы.</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Применение `<wbr>` имеет серьёзный недостаток — понять, перенос перед нами или отдельное слово на другой строке, нельзя. Из-за этого может потеряться смысл предложения и его неправильно поймут. Переносы надо делать по правилам типографики, а именно: в конце строки добавлять дефис. С этим отлично справляется мягкий перенос, в коде HTML для него имеется спецсимвол `&shy;`. Он выполняет ту же роль, что и тег `<wbr>` — не виден в обычном тексте и переносит слово на другую строку, при этом добавляя дефис.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Переносы</title>
  <style>
   .word { 
    width: 160px; 
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p class="word">Один&shy;надцатиклас&shy;сница Анжелика 
  после окончания школы выбрала профессию 
  дело&shy;произ&shy;водитель&shy;ницы.</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

И, наконец, самое мощное и удобное свойство для автоматического добавления переносов — hyphens. Его действие основано на встроенном в браузере словаре переносов, поэтому даёт наилучший результат. Поддерживается в IE10, Firefox, Android и iOS. Chrome и Opera не поддерживают. Чтобы это всё работало, для тега `<html>` добавляем атрибут `lang` со значением `ru`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Переносы</title>
  <style>
   .word { 
    width: 160px; 
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p class="word">Одиннадцатиклассница Анжелика 
  после окончания школы выбрала профессию 
  делопроизводительницы.</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: а где пример с wbr? в первом примере те же shy используются

Comment: Chrome и Opera частично поддерживают, просто не имеют встроенного словаря переносов

Comment: @Grundy добавила с wbr

Answer (score 0):

Не увидел вариант с `white-space:pre-line;`

```css
.post{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:600px;
  text-align:justify;
  margin:30px auto;
  white-space:pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div class="post"> 
  <p> 
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
    
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Смысл ответа в том что переносы будут там где вы их поставите сами без br, wbr,&shy и так далее